# Provider returning null when rebuilding Flutter app

Tags: flutter

I'm pretty new to flutter and I'm trying to make a login system using providers. It seems to be working when I test the login. But when I rebuild the app the provider returns a null value. Any help would be appreciated.

The screen to check for employee data. If it exist it should redirect to the home page. And if it doesn't, it should redirect to the login authenticate page

**Landing Page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class Landing extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LandingState createState() => _LandingState();
}

class _LandingState extends State<Landing> {
  //AuthService auth = new AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Future<Employee> getuserdata() => Employee_preferences().getEmployee();
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => AuthService(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (_) => Employee_Provider(),
        )
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'ClockServe',
        theme: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.blue),
        home: FutureBuilder(
            future: getuserdata(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return CircularProgressIndicator();
                default:
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text('Error:${snapshot.error}');
                  } else if (snapshot.data.empId == null) {
                    return AuthenticatePage();
                  } else {
                    return HomePage(emp: snapshot.data);
                  }
              }
            }),
        routes: {
          '/navigatorPage': (context) => NavigatorPage(),
          '/homePage': (context) => HomePage(),
          '/authenticate': (context) => AuthenticatePage(),
          '/attendancePage': (context) => AttendanceScanner()
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The homepage. The page will hold employee information. Landing page is correctly redirecting to this page but for some reason the provider is returning null

**HomePage**

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Employee emp;
  const HomePage({Key key, this.emp}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  //to do: add back end
  //use futurebuilder to return user object
  //using futureprovider to get snapshot data of user object from database
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Employee emp = Provider.of<Employee_Provider>(context).emp;
    print(emp.empEmail);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () async {
              Employee_preferences().removeEmployee();
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/authenticate');
            },
            label: Text(
              'Log Out',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.logout,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )
        ],
        title: Text('ClockServe'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      //button to pop qr scanner camera
      //after scanning a qr code it should parse the json array
      //into a method, the method will take that as parameter.
      //method should send http request check in the auth dart
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton.extended(
        label: Text('Check In'),
        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
        onPressed: () => navigateToScanPage(context),
      ),
      // floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
      //   onPressed: () {},
      //   child: Icon(Icons.alarm_on),
      // ),

      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(emp.empFirstName ?? 'emp first name'),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Future navigateToScanPage(context) async {
  Navigator.push(
      context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => AttendanceScanner()));
}
```

Code for login page just in case if it's relevant.
Login Page

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;
  LoginPage({this.toggleView});
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email = '';
  String password = '';
  String error = '';
  bool loading = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              widget.toggleView();
            },
            label: Text('Register'),
            icon: Icon(Icons.person_add),
          )
        ],
        title: Text('Login'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(30),
        child: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                WelcomeHeader(),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Enter email' : null,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() => email = val);
                  },
                  decoration: decorationBox.copyWith(hintText: 'Email'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  validator: (value) => value.isEmpty ? 'Enter password' : null,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() => password = val);
                  },
                  obscureText: true,
                  decoration: decorationBox.copyWith(hintText: 'Password'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    final form = _formKey.currentState;
                    if (form.validate()) {
                      form.save();
                      AuthService auth = new AuthService();
                      final Future<Map<String, dynamic>> successMsg =
                          auth.empLogin(email, password);
                      successMsg.then((response) {
                        if (response['status']) {
                          Employee emp = response['employee'];
                          print(emp);
                          Provider.of<Employee_Provider>(context, listen: false)
                              .setEmp(emp);
                          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/homePage');
                        }
                      });
                    }
                  },
                  child: Text('Log In'),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 20.0,
                ),
                Text(
                  error,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20.0),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class WelcomeHeader extends StatelessWidget {
  const WelcomeHeader({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(
            'Welcome To ClockServe',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 28.0,
            ),
          ),
          Divider(
            height: 20,
            thickness: 2,
          ),
          Text(
            'Enter your credentials to login',
            style: TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```